# Google JSON Review Snippet not validating

Tags: json, google-search-console, google-reviews

I'm using the following JSON to produce a review snippet:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org/",
  "@type": "Review",
  "name": "Great service from the start.",
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Chris Tonich"
  },
  "reviewBody": "Very thorough...would highly recommend!",
  "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "4.9",
        "bestRating": "5",
        "ratingCount": "110",
        "itemReviewed": {
            "@type": "Product",
            "image": "https://www.homeintegrity.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/hi-new-logo2.jpg",
            "name": "Pre-Purchase Building Inspections",
            "priceRange": "$$",
            "telephone": "08 8375 8130",
            "address" :{
                "@type": "PostalAddress",
                "streetAddress": "PO Box 163",
                "addressLocality": "Scarborough",
                "addressRegion": "WA",
                "postalCode": "6019",
                "addressCountry": "AU"
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

The Google Rich Snippet Test says:

[image]

Why am I receiving the error when the `Review` contains `aggregateRating` which contains `itemReviewed`?

Why does it say I rated a `Review` rather than an `Item`?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your structure is not according to the schema found on https://schema.org/

A `Review` must contain a field `itemReviewed` (or be embedded in the object, which is reviewed). (see examples at https://schema.org/Review)

A `Review` on the other hand must not contain an `AggregateRating` (see https://schema.org/AggregateRating), because an `AggreateRating` may only be a sub-node of a `Brand`, `CreativeWork`, `Event`, `Offer`, `Organization`, `Place`, `Product`, or `Service`. Note that these types may contain a `Review` too.

---

Your structure roughly is as follows:

- Review "Great service from the start."

  - Author "Chris Tonich"
  - Aggregate rating "4.9"

    - Product "Pre-Purchase Building Inspections"

      - Address "6019 - ..."

What you probably want is something along the lines of:

- LocalBusiness "Pre-Purchase Building Inspections"

  - Address "6019 - ..."
  - Review "Great service from the start."

    - Author "Chris Tonich"
  - Aggregate rating "4.9"